# Codebuild: How to send JSON body to a ENV file in buildspec?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-secrets-manager, buildspec

I have code that takes in a local `test.env.json` that is injected into the start of the test.

However, now that I am running it through `codebuild` and using `secrets manager`, if I don't have a `test.env.json` file then it will not run correctly.

So far I was able to set up the `env` variables in the `buildspec` file correctly but I need to send them to a `test.env.json` file in the commands.

How do I do this?

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: latest
    commands:
      - npm install
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - SECRET="$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id arn:aws:secretsmanager:{secret} | jq '.SecretString | fromjson')"
  build:
    commands:
      - echo $SECRET.   (outputs the correct JSON body)
      - need to send $SECRET to a file called `test.env.json` before npm run
      - npm run test:run
```

Comment: I think it can work, you can also use environment variables directly with ```env: secrets-manager or parameter-store``` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.env.secrets-manager)

Comment: You can always do `echo $SECRET > test.env.json`, but what @FranxiHidro said is the good practice.